# Замена fileSeparator на Formatter (Java)

Tags: java

Задача состоит в том, чтоб заменить fileSeparator на Formatter, но я не до конца понимаю как его тут применить. Сам код создает новый файл по относительному пути

```
public static String сreateFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String relativePath = "Files" + fileSeparator + fileName;
        File file = new File(relativePath);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            return relativePath;
        } else {
            return relativePath;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Тоже не понятно при чем здесь `Formatter`. Может уточните требования? Еще неясно зачем нужен `if` у которого обе ветки одинаковые.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно прошу не хейтить. Но думаю вы так хотели.

```
public static String сreateFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(Locale.US);
    String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    formatter.format("Files%1$s%2$s", fileSeparator, fileName);
    String relativePath = formatter.toString();
    File file = new File(relativePath);
    file.createNewFile();
    return relativePath;
}
```